# add custom UIView and xib into storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uistoryboard, xib

I have a custom `UIView` and xib called `DialPad` and I'm trying to use this object in my storyboard, but the custom DialPad isn't being add as a subview with the buttons

my custom DialPad :UIView

```
@implementation DialPad


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

my custom xib called `DialPad`
[image]

and my view controllers look like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DialPad.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *dial;
@end


#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
    DialPad  *d;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    d = [[DialPad alloc] initWithFrame:self.dial.frame];

    [self.dial addSubview:d];
}    
@end
```

and my storyboard
[image]

but the border around the view looks strange

[image]

```
#import "DialPad.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation DialPad

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading a view from xib file, you should do this:

```
d = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DialPad" owner:nil options:nil]
                 firstObject];
[self.dial addSubview:d];
```

Border: try to add border code in `- (void)awakeFromNib`

Comment: still not seeing any of the buttons, just a clear uiview

Comment: Remove set frame, and don't forget to addsubview. Can you try with edited answer?

Comment: And check outlet connection also.

Comment: thank you, i removed the initWithFrame in the custom class and used your suggestions, looks perfect, thanks again

Comment: one more question, when i add a border to the custom DialPad view it adds a border to the entire view controller also

Comment: Maybe you should create a question for this. I will try to support. Too many things are unclear. What "view"? "view controller"? about code "add a border"?.